# Как вырезать поддомен с строки?

Tags: php, строки

Пример строки:

```
S:/domains/account.site.com

S:/domains/support.site.com

S:/domains/company.site.com

S:/domains/forum.site.com
```

Вопрос:

Как вырезать с строки поддомен не зная его, вместе с точкой?

Comment: пройдитесь регулярочкой. Должно помочь

Comment: Прошу помочь с регуляркой

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qB6cOy/1

Comment: Вижу, но не могу понять где сама регулярка?

Comment: то зачит вырезать в данном контексте? достать для дальнейшего использования или удалить из строки?

Comment: Удалить из строки

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '
    S:/domains/account.site.com
    S:/domains/support.site.com
    S:/domains/company.site.com
    S:/domains/forum.site.com
';

echo preg_replace('/S:\/domains\/\K[^\.]+\.(?=site\.com)/', '', $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZoeJZ

https://regex101.com/r/qB6cOy/1